# using ols from statsmodels.formula.api with only a constant term?

Tags: statsmodels, least-squares

I'd like to show students what happens when only a constant is used in a regression model.  I specified one model as price ~ age for an OLS model of the price of used cars as a  function of age plus a constant.  Now I'd like to drop the age variable and just have the constant.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 4):

The formula fitting in statsmodels uses [Patsy](https://patsy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/formulas.html), which tries to mimic R-style model specifications.

Since you didn't specify a data source, I've taken a dataset from the
statsmodels [OLS guide](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/example_formulas.html) to provide a worked example - can wealth explain lottery spending:

```py
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

# load example and trim to a few features
df = sm.datasets.get_rdataset("Guerry", "HistData").data
df = df[['Lottery', 'Literacy', 'Wealth', 'Region']].dropna()

# fit with y=mx + c 
model1 = smf.ols(formula='Lottery ~ Wealth', data=df).fit()
print(model1.summary())

# fit with y=c (only an intercept)
model2 = smf.ols(formula='Lottery ~ 1', data=df).fit()
print(model2.summary())
```

For your question, a model with only the intercept is nothing more than the mean, but presumably you are interested in techniques for comparing different models, so let's do a quick comparison to see whether the simpler model gives a better fit - one option is the f-test:

```py
f_val, p_val, _ = model1.compare_f_test(model2)
print(f_val, p_val, p_val<0.01)
```

The p value is below 1% significance level, so we interpret that the more complex model is "more correct" in this case.

For completeness, to specify a model without an intercept (useful e.g. if we already mean-centered the data), we can exclude with `-1` in the formula:

```py
# y = mx
model3 = smf.ols(formula='Lottery ~ Wealth -1', data=df).fit()
print(model3.summary())

f_val, p_val, _ = model1.compare_f_test(model3)
print(f_val, p_val, p_val<0.01)
```

Again, p_val is below 1% significance level, so including intercept and slope improves model fit. (No multi-test correction here, but p values are <<1%)

Comment: This was very helpful.  I thought it would be along this line but it didn't work for me at first.  Now I have what I want.  Incidentally, the purpose is to show the students that the mean is just an OLS solution.  The formula for the mean came from somewhere.  This will show that it came from an OLS problem.  Thanks again for the help.

Comment: I'm happy to hear this helped - since you say this solves your problem, consider accepting the answer too ([click the green tick](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/208898) at the top left of answer).